# Actualiza los estados pero el segundo objeto siempre lo muestra vacio

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy tratando desarrollando una web app haciendo uso de `React Js`, pero me he topado con un inconveniente, el cual no entiendo por que ocurre.

[image: web app react]

Lo que esta encerrado en el rectángulo color rojo, es un componente, y lo que esta encerrado con el color verde, es otro. Yo realizo el siguiente procedimiento, para poder ejecutar una función.

Lo ideal es poder obtener la información, tanto de la petición que hago a ***google maps***, enviando una dirección, o ingresando por teclado la otra información en el otro componente.

#### Orden

1. Obtener la dirección y geo posición, luego de ingresar el formato establecido
2. Si es correcta, cambio un estado, de `false` a `true`
3. Como no ha sido alterado el estado que pertenece al otro componente, aun no sucede nada
4. Escribo los valores en las cajas de texto a la derecha
5. Si cumplen con lo establecido, entonces, cambia el estado de de `false` a `true`
6. Debido a que ambos estados ahora son `true`, Se ejecuta la función, pero los datos del objeto que hace relación a las cajas de texto de la derecha, que actualizan, siempre son vacíos.

#### Código componente padre

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import AddressInput from './components/address.js';
import InputDataPerson from './components/dataPersonHouse.js';
import TableConsumeInformation from './components/tableInformation.js';

import './styles/main.css';

class App extends Component{

    constructor(){

        super();
        this.state = {
            geoInfo:{                
                Latitude:"",
                Longitude:""
            },
            dataInfoHouse:{
                year:"",
                anguloInclinacion: "",
                potenciaPaneles: "",
                diasNoSoleados: ""
            },
            activate:{
                adress: false,
                dataHouse: false
            }
        };

        this.updateGeoInfo = this.updateGeoInfo.bind(this);
        this.updateInfoHouse = this.updateInfoHouse.bind(this);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>                
                <div className="Contenedor">  
                    <div className="Espacio">
                        <AddressInput newInfo={this.updateGeoInfo}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="Espacio">
                        <InputDataPerson newInfo={this.updateInfoHouse}/>
                    </div>                                 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <TableConsumeInformation ref={instance => { this.tableInformation = instance; }}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    updateGeoInfo(geoData){

        let geoInfo = Object.assign({}, this.state.geoInfo);
        let activate = Object.assign({}, this.state.activate);
        let infoNASARequest = {
            dataHome:"",
            dataGeo:""
        };

        geoInfo.Latitude = geoData.ltd;
        geoInfo.Longitude = geoData.lng;

        this.setState({geoInfo});

        activate.adress = true; 
        this.setState({activate}); 

        if(activate.adress == true && activate.dataHouse == true){  
            console.log("ambas posicion geo");
            this.sendInfoNasaRequest();
        }

    }

    updateInfoHouse(dataHouse){

        let infoHouse = Object.assign({}, this.state.dataInfoHouse);
        let activate = Object.assign({}, this.state.activate);
        let infoNASARequest = {
            dataHome:"",
            dataGeo:""
        };

        infoHouse.year = dataHouse.year;
        infoHouse.potenciaPaneles = dataHouse.potenciaPanel;
        infoHouse.diasNoSoleados = dataHouse.diasNoSoleados;
        infoHouse.anguloInclinacion = dataHouse.anguloInclinacion;

        this.setState({infoHouse});

        activate.dataHouse = true;
        this.setState({activate});        

        if(activate.adress == true && activate.dataHouse == true){
            console.log("ambas en informacion de la casa");
            this.sendInfoNasaRequest();
        }

    }   

    sendInfoNasaRequest(){
        let infoNASARequest = {
            dataGeo:this.state.geoInfo,
            dataHome:this.state.dataInfoHouse                
        };
        this.tableInformation.CalculateRadiation(infoNASARequest);
    }

}

export default App;
```

***Nota:*** Los valores del objeto que guardo en `dataHome`, siempre son vacíos.

Comment: Ambos componentes tienen el mismo padre? O como es su estructura?

Comment: @KacosPro que mas, si están en el mismo padre, los importo al mismo padre

Comment: Agrega el código del componente padre :)

Comment: deja lo agrego completo espera

Answer (score 1):

la funcion setState() es asyncronica, si quieres que ocurra algo despues de modificar el state, puedes pasarle un callback, asi: 
this.setState({}, () => { ...aqui... })

Comment: Podrías poner un ejmeplo completo?